# Android: NPE when calling getIntent().getParcelableExtra() twice in a DetailActivity (2 different json model classes both with Id field)

Tags: android, retrofit

Recently began experimenting with Retrofit. Specifically, with [themoviedb.org API](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#).

Currently displaying list of popular movies in `MainActivity`. Clicking a movie launches the `DetailActivity` and displays some details for that particular movie including Cast and Crew.

Clicking a Cast member launches a `FilmographyActivity` - displaying the movie poster for each movie that particular actor has been in.

**Problem:**
I'm then trying to click a movie from the `FilmographyActivity` --> grab that particular movie's unique ID --> and pass it into the `DetailsActivity`. (Or is it possible to set the ID from `List<ActorCast>` equal to the ID from `List<MovieInfo>`? These are two of the classes I've generated from using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Relevant code:

MovieDetailActivity.java

```
public static final String EXTRA_MOVIE = "movie";
public static final String EXTRA_ACTOR = "actor";
MovieInfo mMovieInfo;
ActorCast mActorCast;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);

        // Here's where I think/know I'm screwing things up:
        if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE)) {
            mMovieInfo = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE);
        } else if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_ACTOR)){
            mActorCast = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_ACTOR);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Detail Activity IllegalArgumentException");
    }

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mMovieInfo.getTitle());
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    title.setText(mMovieInfo.title);
    description.setText(mMovieInfo.overview);
    voteCount.setText(String.valueOf(mMovieInfo.voteCount));

    .....

} // end onCreate
```

And part of the PopularMoviesAdapter:

```
    private Context mContext;
    private List<MovieInfo> list;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final MovieInfo currentMovie = list.get(position);

    ...
        holder.moviePoster.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked: " + currentMovie.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, list.get(position));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
} // end onBindViewHolder
```

And part of the FilmographyAdapter:

```
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<ActorCast> list;

public ActorAdapter(Context context, List<ActorCast> actorCast){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.list = actorCast;
}

.....

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ActorViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ActorCast actor = list.get(position);

        holder.actorCreditMovieImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked: " + actor.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_ACTOR, actorInfoList.get(position).getId());

            intent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_ACTOR, list.get(position).id);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I probably need to take a step back and look at the "big picture" of what's going on - been staring at it for a bit too long.

Here's what my Interface calls look like:

```
public interface PopMoviesInterface {

    @GET("3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=308be8a6ec40318471fb3c4d177c0382")
    Call<MovieResult> allItems(@Query("page") int page);

    @GET("3/person/{id}/movie_credits")
    Call<ActorResult> showActorHistory(@Path("id") String id, @Query("api_key") String key);

    @GET("3/movie/{movie}/credits")
    Call<CreditsList> listCredits(@Path("movie") String movie, @Query("api_key") String key);

}
```

And the logcat:

```
04-27 21:47:06.596 19486-19486/com.example.user.retrofit2moviedemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.retrofit2moviedemo, PID: 19486
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.retrofit2moviedemo/com.example.user.retrofit2moviedemo.MovieDetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Detail Activity IllegalArgumentException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Detail Activity IllegalArgumentException
at com.example.user.retrofit2moviedemo.MovieDetailActivity.onCreate(MovieDetailActivity.java:101)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any suggestions, advice or a point in the right direction is appreciated.

**Edit**

Here are my POJOs. Note: Not all of the "fields" (am I using this term right?) in MovieInfo are found in ActorCast, such as "overview" "voteCount" and a few others. So, when clicking a movie in the FilmographyActivity, it won't just automatically get the overview etc since that field isn't found in ActorCast.java.

`MovieInfo.java` (which is tied to `MovieResult.java`

```
public class MovieInfo implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    public String posterPath;
    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    public Boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    public String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    public String releaseDate;
    @SerializedName("id") //THIS IS THE UNIVERSAL MOVIE ID
    @Expose
    public Integer id;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    @Expose
    public String originalTitle;
    ... // Not showing Other fields like popularity, voteCount etc to save space
    ...
    // getters and setters

    public static final Creator<MovieInfo> CREATOR = new Creator<MovieInfo>() {
        @Override
        public MovieInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MovieInfo(in);
        }
        @Override
        public MovieInfo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MovieInfo[size];
        }
    };

    public MovieInfo(Parcel in){
        id = in.readInt();
        title = in.readString();
        posterPath = in.readString();
        overview = in.readString();
        backdropPath = in.readString();
        voteAverage = in.readDouble();
        voteCount = in.readInt();
        releaseDate = in.readString();
    }

    public MovieInfo(int id, String title, String poster, String plot, 
                 double rating, String release, String backdrop, int voteCount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.posterPath = poster;
        this.overview = plot;
        this.backdropPath = backdrop;
        this.voteAverage = rating;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
        this.releaseDate = release;
    }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
            parcel.writeInt(id);
            parcel.writeString(title);
            parcel.writeString(posterPath);
            parcel.writeString(overview);
            parcel.writeString(backdropPath);
            parcel.writeDouble(voteAverage);
            parcel.writeInt(voteCount);
            parcel.writeString(releaseDate);
        }
```

MovieResult.java

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class MovieResult {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    public Integer page;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    public List<MovieInfo> results = new ArrayList<MovieInfo>();
    @SerializedName("total_results")
    @Expose
    public Integer totalResults;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    public Integer totalPages;
    // getters and setters
```

The two below deal with the Filmography.

ActorCast.java

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class ActorCast implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    public Boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("character")
    @Expose
    public String character;
    @SerializedName("credit_id")
    @Expose
    public String creditId;
    @SerializedName("id") //THIS IS THE UNIVERSAL MOVIE ID
    @Expose
    public Integer id;
    // few other fields not included to save space. 
    // getters and setters
    // Parcelable methods here
```

And ActorResult.java

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class ActorResult {

    @SerializedName("cast")
    @Expose
    public List<ActorCast> cast = new ArrayList<ActorCast>();
    @SerializedName("crew")
    @Expose
    public List<ActorCrew> crew = new ArrayList<ActorCrew>();
    @SerializedName("id") //THIS IS THE ACTOR ID
    @Expose
    public Integer id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem you aren't getting the ID in MovieDetailActivity you expect because of a NPE? That's what the title indicates, if so I think `getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE);` is what you are after, instead of `getParceableExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE);`

Comment: Apologies for the poorly worded title. I've edited my question to include some of the POJOs which are implementing Parcelable. Right now, for example, if I click on the movie "Deadpool" my toast will give the ID # 293660 and launch the Details Activity. Since my Details Activity is also showing the movie's cast, I'll then click "Ryan Reynolds." Finally, this takes me to the Filmography Activity for Reynolds. If I scroll through his movies and click "Deadpool" my Toast will display the correct movie ID. But if I try passing this to Details Activity, I get the crash. Should I use Serializable?